# How can i check all my categories have META Tags Values (Title, Desc, Keywords)

Tags: magento-1.9, category, seo, meta-tags

I need to check my all categories have proper meta tags (title, description, keywords). Which table stored category meta tags (title, description, keywords) value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this ...

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$attributes = array('name', 'meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keywords');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);

$out = array();
foreach ($collection as $category) {
    $out[$category->getId()] = array(
        $category->getData('name'),
        $category->getData('meta_title'),
        $category->getData('meta_description'),
        $category->getData('meta_keywords')
    );
}

var_dump($out);
```

**Edit:** for CSV-Export:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($out as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /home/xyz/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 463.............     how can i solve this....

Comment: Sounds like missing `Mage::app()` ... updated answer.

Comment: working good, how can i export by csv

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: is my code right  http://www.codesend.com/view/4ec0b58a35521779ecd7cb2d54659a44/

Comment: No ;) Move code for CSV to the end ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60507/discussion-between-rathinam-and-sv3n).

Comment: It's working,    thank you for your support.

Comment: Is possible to import by using SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

This data is all in either **catalog_category_entity_text** or **catalog_category_entity_varchar** tables. The following sql will get all the category names (and paths just in case you have duplicate category names) where the description is NULL. You will have to find the relevant entity_id values for the other data you want. (The values I have given below are specifically for my database - yours may be different). I hope this gets you started

```
select ccev.value as name,ccet.value as description,cce.path from catalog_category_entity cce 
join catalog_category_entity_text ccet on cce.entity_id = ccet.entity_id
join catalog_category_entity_varchar ccev on cce.entity_id =ccev.entity_id
where ccet.attribute_id='44'
and ccev.attribute_id='41'
and ccet.value is NULL
```

Comment: Actually above query display only main category, All my main category have meta tags, still showing null value, how can I solve this and, how can I view my child category and grandchild category details also.

Comment: It's returning all categories for me :/
@sv3n 's approach is probably better ;)

Comment: could you pls send me your result screen shots, for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: my result : https://snag.gy/TByR81.jpg

Comment: my result https://snag.gy/Pp2VAQ.jpg showing a similar path structure. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I need to confirm all my categories consists page title, meta description, and meta keywords.